# Problem in executing the memory stage that can perform call, ret, pop, etc

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, memory, processor

I am trying to implement a Y86 processor for my college assignment.

This is my `MemoryStage`:

```
module MemoryStage(
    input [31:0] val_e,
    input [31:0] val_a,
    input [31:0] val_p,
    input [31:0] val_b,
    input [3:0] icode,
    input wr,
    input rd,
    input cs,
    output reg [31:0] val_m,
    output reg read_success
);

    parameter addr_size = 10;
    parameter word_size = 64;
    parameter memory_size = 1024;

    input [addr_size-1:0] addr;
    input [word_size-1:0] data_in;
    output reg [word_size-1:0] data_out;
    reg [word_size-1:0] mem [memory_size-1:0];

    // Memory read operation
    always @(*) begin
        if (rd && cs) begin
            if (addr < memory_size) begin
                data_out = mem[addr];
                read_success = 1;
            end else begin
                data_out = 0;
                read_success = 0;
            end
        end
    end

    // Memory write operation
    always @(*) begin
        if (wr && cs)
            mem[addr] <= data_in;
    end

    // Memory stage logic
    always @(*) begin
        // Determine memory address
        case (icode)
            // Instructions that write to memory
            4'b0001, 4'b0011, 4'b0101, 4'b0111, 4'b1001, 4'b1011, 4'b1101: val_m = val_e; // Address calculation result
            // Instructions that read from memory (push, call, return)
            4'b1010, 4'b1110: val_m = val_p; // Next instruction address for call
            // Instructions that read from memory (pop, return)
            4'b1100, 4'b1111: val_m = val_b; // Stack pointer for pop
            default: val_m = 32'b0; // Default to zero
        endcase
    end

endmodule
```

I used [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9_af4dJoSrI) as a reference to make my module.

On a separate note:

> DecodeStage.v:6: error: Ports cannot be unpacked arrays. Try enabling
> SystemVerilog support.

Can you help me with this error too?

Comment: Does that error message really come from the code you posted?  You have a module named `MemoryStage` in a file named `DecodeStage.v`?  Typically, the file name and module match.

Answer (score 1):

I see a couple of problems:

1. `addr`, `data_in` and `data_out` are not defined in the module I/O list.
2. I see why you have defined them below is because you want to parameterize them. So if you declare the output above, you have to write your parameterize logic differently. One approach is as below (you can study more about this approach [here](https://www.realdigital.org/doc/43c79714a7f3d0bbb8098d60c63fde48#:%7E:text=When%20defining%20a%20parameterized%20module,parameter%20and%20which%20are%20not.)).

```
module MemoryStage #(
    parameter addr_size = 10,
    parameter word_size = 64,
    parameter memory_size = 1024
)
(
    input [31:0] val_e,
    input [31:0] val_a,
    input [31:0] val_p,
    input [31:0] val_b,
    input [3:0] icode,
    input wr,
    input rd,
    input cs,
    output reg [31:0] val_m,
    output reg read_success,
    
    input [addr_size-1:0] addr,
    input [word_size-1:0] data_in,
    output reg [word_size-1:0] data_out
);
```

3. Since there is no sequential logic here, there is no need of using the Non-Blocking statement (`<=`) in your logic.
4. `val_a` is unused.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to all the syntax errors and style issues addressed by the [other answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/702143/72936), there is another issue.

By the absence of a clock signal and your usage of `always @(*)` everywhere, this implies that you intend to infer only combinational logic in your module.  However, if you were to synthesize this module, you would infer latches, not purely combinational logic.

You either need to add a clock signal to infer sequential logic where you want it, or you need to re-code if you want to avoid latches.

To avoid latches, you need to make assignments to all branches of an `if/else`.  For example:

```
// Memory read operation
always @(*) begin
    if (rd && cs) begin
        if (addr < memory_size) begin
            data_out = mem[addr];
            read_success = 1;
        end else begin
            data_out = 0;
            read_success = 0;
        end
    end else begin
        data_out = 0;
        read_success = 0;
    end
end
```

Something similar is needed for the `// Memory write operation`, although that really looks like you want to infer sequential logic there.

The `// Memory stage logic` is fine as it is because you used `default`.